# Monotouch LLVM compiler doesn't work

Tags: linker, xamarin.ios, llvm

Hello all I hope I can find a solution for this,I have my project in monotouch and I have configured my AdHoc profile for test on devices, I am able to generate the apps using the standard compiler, but when I want to use the LLVM compiler this compilation process literally never ends .. I left my mac turned on all the night .. I even tried changing the linker options (I know is not recommended). In short I tried with link sdk assemblies only and with don't link. Still the process never ends. If someone is experiencing the she problems and could help me please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Never seen this - but that's definitively a bug and should be [reported](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) to Xamarin.

Please trying adding `-v -v -v` to your **Additional mtouch arguments** (in the project's options) so the verbosity will be at the maximum.

The rebuild and switch the the "Build Output" (it's in the **Error List** pad inside MonoDevelop). Once it seems stopped copy-paste the log and include it in the bug report. That should give enough information to diagnose the issue.